# How to calculate how many times a HTML, CSS and JS file is loaded using JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

I am working on a Web App project where I am using JSP. I am trying to count no.of Hits(no.of times each and every file is loaded) happened in my Web App. For this, I have to calculate how many numbers of times each and every HTML, CSS, js, JSP, servlets and almost every file that is used to provide a particular page.

If anyone have a solution or know any resources on how to achieve this kind of problem please provide me links or answers.

I am using Apache tomcat server and MySQL.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The conventional definition of hits implies how many times a page or site was visited. Not how many JavaScript files it loaded. Are you sure your problem requires you to measure number of file accesses and not page access?

Comment: Apache Tomcat generates a very detailed access log file. You will find it in Tomcats' "logs" directory. The default file name is  localhost_access_log.YYYY-MM-dd.txt. Look inside and enjoy...

Comment: @Timir I was able to calculate the number of views of each page(no.of times that page is loaded) using a simple counter and Visits to my page using counting no.of sessions(session implicit Object of JSP) created till then. Now I am trying to calculate how many numbers of times each file is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to count is to create a filter that counts every requests and maintains the map of request-counts. Everytime request goes through the filter you just check and increase the count if request is already in the map. For the specific jsps, you can add some tail identifier specific to that jsp to all contents inside the jsp in order to identify the request is coming for that jsp.

You can further categorize the request for css, jsp and all. You get the idea.